# Finding equivalent equation for matrix from regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression

In lecture on Bayesian estimators, we have while deriving some expectation this:
$$ X^T - AXX^T - A = 0 $$
where $X$ is a $n \times p$ predictor matrix with rank $p$ and $A$ is $p \times n $ matrix such that :
$$\beta = Ay + z$$
and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $y$ and $z$ are independent random variables with Gaussian probability distribution. 
From these two function, they are able to derive to:
$$A = (X^TX + I_p)^{-1}X^T$$while I am only able to come up to:
$$A = X^T(XX^T + I_p)^{-1}$$
What am I doing wrong? Or missing here? Not that $X^TX$ is symmetric matrix.

Comment: Any possibility that they wrote it down incorrectly?

Comment: Nope, what do you assume might that might be wrong? Maybe I wrote something wrong.

Comment: I tried working through this and I got exactly what you got.  I'm not convinced the other equation is correct.  If this was a lecture and the person just quoted the result without deriving it, then there's a possibility they wrote it down incorrectly.

Comment: Thing is, he is referencing it through a lot of pages both on his lecture notex and couorse notes, so I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: That's a little unsettling.  I would highly recommend asking him and showing your derivation.  It's quite possible they worked through the details long before putting their notes together and simply forgot that the terms should be reversed.  Just an observation, your term should actually have $I_n$ in it since $XX^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Yep, that's right, mistake while transfering to latex.